# NodeJS: retrieving an array which is wrapped in a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailgun

I'm currently trying to save a mail object () I'm getting back from an API into our Mongo database.
This is all fine for all values being passed accept the field 'attachments'. The attachments are supposed to be an array of objects, but this is wrapped in a string. My question now is: how do I get the array out of that string?

Example of the req.body which I'm getting from the POST request:

> { timestamp: '1538728432',   token:
>   '0a1336769443d5a593d0ef7c1c817d29ef64ba422fc3cc45f1',   signature:
>   'c44c67660f0ad97bbb5ece92c733302d4511d4607b5787ae6aa8f2203b0e2e3e',
>   domain: 'karaton.uk',   From: '',
>   'X-Envelope-From': '',   To: '', 
>   'Dkim-Signature': 'v=1; a=rsa-sha256;
>   c=relaxed/relaxed;\td=karaton.be;
>   s=20140924;\th=content-type:subject:reply-to:from:to:message-id:mime-version:date:from;\tbh=Xfm+LiX4NVMKTRaQB7gNUXf6z8yVjUqn23aenMee/q4=;\tb=JEslFgXEsO3/kW3khZFF6F4HEo9Mwx+oXJH5DGsXALaGa98ki9o5tLddmEcClqhZ8IJLR0+vrMJ3x\t
>   zU5ThqHNElHpt6VE9MX5ZSHJHnI2kiEXq7MN5BUWfStlS2stYwooZcuZKOkbZXRaUHODewUQbhvZQD\t
>   5/eA5RltbAOqwIaA=',   from: '',   'User-Agent':
>   'One.com webmail 27.8.5',   Date: 'Fri, 05 Oct 2018 10:21:49 +0200',
>   'Message-Id': '<1538727709180.51726.8212@webmail12>',
>   'Mime-Version': '1.0',   Received:    [ 'from
>   mailrelay4-2.pub.mailoutpod1-cph3.one.com
>   (mailrelay4-2.pub.mailoutpod1-cph3.one.com [46.30.212.3]) by
>   mxa.mailgun.org with ESMTP id 5bb71f1f.7f030c2a1580-smtp-in-n02; Fri,
>   05 Oct 2018 08:21:51 -0000 (UTC)',
>        'from onecom-webmail2 94.143.189.242 (unknown [46.30.211.130])\tby mailrelay4.pub.mailoutpod1-cph3.one.com (Halon)
>   with ESMTPSA\tid b4d6415f-c877-11e8-86b7-d0431ea8bb10;\tFri, 05 Oct
>   2018 08:21:49 +0000 (UTC)' ],   'X-Halone-Cookie':
>   'c9ea0f7e80128b5bfaf5bf8d8aca6fced5bcb162',   subject: '2
>   attachments',   'message-url':
>   'https://se.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/karaton.uk/messages/eyJwIjpmYWxzZSwiayI6IjEyNzQ1ZmViLTM4OTItNDdkZC04MTJiLWJlYzU4ZjNjYTI4MCIsInMiOiI1NDE1ODQ0ZjIyIiwiYyI6InRhbmtiIn0=',
>   'Reply-To': '',   recipient: 'tho@karaton.uk',
>   sender: 'thomas.l@karaton.be',   'X-Mailgun-Incoming': 'Yes',
>   'message-headers': '[["X-Mailgun-Incoming", "Yes"],
>   ["X-Envelope-From", ""], ["Received", "from
>   mailrelay4-2.pub.mailoutpod1-cph3.one.com
>   (mailrelay4-2.pub.mailoutpod1-cph3.one.com [46.30.212.3]) by
>   mxa.mailgun.org with ESMTP id 5bb71f1f.7f030c2a1580-smtp-in-n02; Fri,
>   05 Oct 2018 08:21:51 -0000 (UTC)"], ["Dkim-Signature", "v=1;
>   a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;\td=karaton.be;
>   s=20140924;\th=content-type:subject:reply-to:from:to:message-id:mime-version:date:from;\tbh=Xfm+LiX4NVMKTRaQB7gNUXf6z8yVjUqn23aenMee/q4=;\tb=JEslFgXEsO3/kW3khZFF6F4HEo9Mwx+oXJH5DGsXALaGa98ki9o5tLddmEcClqhZ8IJLR0+vrMJ3x\t
>   zU5ThqHNElHpt6VE9MX5ZSHJHnI2kiEXq7MN5BUWfStlS2stYwooZcuZKOkbZXRaUHODewUQbhvZQD\t
>   5/eA5RltbAOqwIaA="], ["X-Halone-Cookie",
>   "c9ea0f7e80128b5bfaf5bf8d8aca6fced5bcb162"], ["X-Halone-Id",
>   "b4d6415f-c877-11e8-86b7-d0431ea8bb10"], ["Received", "from
>   onecom-webmail2 94.143.189.242 (unknown [46.30.211.130])\tby
>   mailrelay4.pub.mailoutpod1-cph3.one.com (Halon) with ESMTPSA\tid
>   b4d6415f-c877-11e8-86b7-d0431ea8bb10;\tFri, 05 Oct 2018 08:21:49
>   +0000 (UTC)"], ["X-Originating-Ip", "94.143.189.242"], ["User-Agent", "One.com webmail 27.8.5"], ["Date", "Fri, 05 Oct 2018 10:21:49
>   +0200"], ["Mime-Version", "1.0"], ["Message-Id", "<1538727709180.51726.8212@webmail12>"], ["To", ""],
>   ["From", ""], ["Reply-To",
>   ""], ["Subject", "2 attachments"],
>   ["Content-Type", "multipart/mixed;
>   boundary=\"----------8210-1538727709180-1\""]]',   'X-Halone-Id':
>   'b4d6415f-c877-11e8-86b7-d0431ea8bb10',   'Content-Type':
>   'multipart/mixed; boundary="----------8210-1538727709180-1"',
>   'X-Originating-Ip': '94.143.189.242',   Subject: '2 attachments',
>   attachments: '[{"url":
>   "https://se.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/karaton.uk/messages/eyJwIjpmYWxzZSwiayI6IjEyNzQ1ZmViLTM4OTItNDdkZC04MTJiLWJlYzU4ZjNjYTI4MCIsInMiOiI1NDE1ODQ0ZjIyIiwiYyI6InRhbmtiIn0=/attachments/0",
>   "content-type": "application/pdf", "name": "WOORDZOEKER maken _ Online
>   _ Met oplossing2 copy.pdf", "size": 53398}, {"url": "https://se.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/karaton.uk/messages/eyJwIjpmYWxzZSwiayI6IjEyNzQ1ZmViLTM4OTItNDdkZC04MTJiLWJlYzU4ZjNjYTI4MCIsInMiOiI1NDE1ODQ0ZjIyIiwiYyI6InRhbmtiIn0=/attachments/1",
>   "content-type":
>   "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
>   "name": "Geschatte uren.xlsx", "size": 44210}]',   'body-plain':
>   '\r\n\r\n',   'body-html': '
> \r\n',   'stripped-html':
>   '
> \n',   'stripped-text': '',   'stripped-signature': ''
>   }

Comment: `JSON.parse(req.body.attachments)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in `JSON.parse()` function, it'll return an array of objects as it should. It's opposed to `JSON.stringify()`, which does the opposite. So, basically, 
`JSON.parse(req.body.attachments)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse` should do the trick

```js
const response = {
  timestamp: '1538728432',
  token: '0a1336769443d5a593d0ef7c1c817d29ef64ba422fc3cc45f1',
  Subject: '2 attachments',
  attachments: '[{"url": "https://se.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/karaton.uk/messages/eyJwIjpmYWxzZSwiayI6IjEyNzQ1ZmViLTM4OTItNDdkZC04MTJiLWJlYzU4ZjNjYTI4MCIsInMiOiI1NDE1ODQ0ZjIyIiwiYyI6InRhbmtiIn0=/attachments/0", "content-type": "application/pdf", "name": "WOORDZOEKER maken _ Online _ Met oplossing2 copy.pdf", "size": 53398}, {"url": "https://se.api.mailgun.net/v3/domains/karaton.uk/messages/eyJwIjpmYWxzZSwiayI6IjEyNzQ1ZmViLTM4OTItNDdkZC04MTJiLWJlYzU4ZjNjYTI4MCIsInMiOiI1NDE1ODQ0ZjIyIiwiYyI6InRhbmtiIn0=/attachments/1", "content-type": "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "name": "Geschatte uren.xlsx", "size": 44210}]'
}

const attachments = JSON.parse(response.attachments);
console.log(attachments[0]);
console.log(attachments[1]);
```

Ref:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse